# get() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: processing

I need to create an overlay image with variable-defined size. However, if I use `surface.setSize()` when I then try to store the resulting image with `get()` the sketch crashes with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Why? Does `size()` initialize the canvas differently?

```java
final int w = 320;
final int h = 240;

PImage overlay;

void setup() {
  surface.setSize(w, h); // remove it, and you're ok
  background(0);         // draw something
  overlay = get();       // exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/3935) issue, I can't comment much on the "why" of things here but as far as I can understand, `setSize()` runs after setup is finished because it can't run while things(in this case, the background) are being drawn. Moving that line to the end of setup doesn't produce the out of bounds exception:

```java
final int w = 320;
final int h = 240;    

PImage overlay;

void setup() {    
  background(0,200,150);      
  overlay = get();       
  surface.setSize(w, h);
}

void draw() {
  tint(0,200,0);
  image(overlay,50,0);
}
```

**Edit**: It seems like the `get()` in this case is grabbing only the default window size of pixels

There is a workaround for that- you can start by declaring `size` with some reasonable or basically any dimensions bigger than `w` and `h`, then use the `get()` method with 4 parameters to grab the image according to the `w` and `h` dimensions:

```java
final int w = 320;
final int h = 240;

PImage overlay;

void setup() {

  size(1000, 1000); //can be any numbers greater than w and h
  background(0, 200, 150);      
  surface.setSize(w, h);
  overlay = get(0, 0, w, h);
}

void draw() {
  tint(0, 200, 0);
  image(overlay, 50, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're using `surface.setSize()` instead of `size()` because you got an error when you tried to pass variables into the `size()` function?

The solution to that problem is **not** to call the `surface.setSize()` function. Instead, you should define a `settings()` function that then calls the `size()` function with variables as parameters. The rest of your code would remain in the `setup()` function.

```java
final int w = 320;
final int h = 240;

PImage overlay;

void settings() {
  size(w, h);
}

void setup() {
  background(0);
  overlay = get();
}
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/settings_.html).

Another approach would be to get rid of the `w` and `h` variables entirely, and just pass in numbers to the `size()` function. Then you could just use the `width` and `height` variables wherever you were previously using the `w` and `h` variables.